# View All Assigned Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: keyboard

Is there a way (probably an app) that lets you see all global (and possibly local) keyboard shortcuts that have been defined? Something similar to [ActiveHotkeys](http://download.cnet.com/ActiveHotkeys/3000-2086_4-10914399.html) on Windows. I dislike assigning new keyboard shortcuts without being sure that they won't cause shortcut collision.

Comment: That's a great first question. I hope someone has an equally great answer!

Comment: Related to collisions: [Global keyboard shortcut conflicts](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/13410/8546)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a rather expensive program that does just this. I installed it on several classroom Macs, to help new users learn keyboard shortcuts:

- [KeyCue](http://www.ergonis.com/products/keycue/) by Ergonis Software.

Works well, easy to use, but at $28.00 a little pricy.

Comment: This looks great. $28 is a little pricy for a utility like this, but I think the trial version should suffice.

Answer (score 7):

There is a very nice app that's freely available to show you all shortcuts when you hold down the command key a bit longer than normal.

- http://www.cheatsheetapp.com/CheatSheet/

It works on Mavericks and several older OS and I've never had problems with it other than forgetting to quit it after I'm done discovering shortcut keys. It appears to be advertisement supported, so consider that if you prefer to pay to support developers as opposed to be part of what's being sold.

Comment: It's a great app but for minimising the risk of collision, it doesn't show *all* shortcuts. (Neither does KeyCue, but KeyCue *can* show more.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Windows user so I'm unsure of what ActiveHotKeys does. However, on System Preferences on the Mac OS X, there's a Keyboard preferences which when clicked will display "Keyboard Shortcuts" (the choice to the right of "Keyboard").

Hope this helps, and please mark your question as answered if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I realized I didn't really explain at all what ActiveHotKeys does, and that link isn't that helpful. http://www.freewaregenius.com/2009/05/06/activehotkeys-reveals-used-hotkeys-on-your-system/ does a better explanation; basically, it shows you all shortcuts that are assigned to all applications.

Answer (score -2):

There is a cool widget for dashboard by dashkards that has both general OSX shortcuts as well as a good list for several common apps. Its got a small ad banner, but it's quick to access which is nice. http://dashkards.com